# displaying css style in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a apsx page and in that page I have two buttons called save and cancel, i need to display this with some css style, my script is

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="bar">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my css script is

```
.bar
{
background-position: center;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCCC;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 30px;
border-top-style: solid;
}
```

and am getting the style as

[image]

I have few more controls above these save and cancel buttons...the problems is this save and cancel buttons with the bar style comes right after the controls above them....

now these buttons are displaying at the center of the page and I need to display these save and cancel buttons with the bar style at the bottom of the page....how can I do this..

note:I put the position:absolute, it will disturb the alignments in other forms, coz am using this same bar style in all my forms......in other forms I have the controls that fills the page and automatically the save cancel buttons are coming at the bottom, but here I have only 4 controls...so the save and cancel button is at center, thats what am trying to display at the buttom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SX7n3/6/

For one, lose the table...

```
<div id="content">
    Hello World!
</div>

<div class="clear">&#160;</div>

<div class="bar">
    <div class="buttons">    
          <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>    
</div>    

.content
{
    min-height:800px;
    width: 100%;
}

.bar
{
    padding-top: 4px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.buttons
{
    float: right;        
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: now also the bar is at the same center position,not at the bottom

Comment: Set a min-height: 800px; in the content div above your bar and put a div with clear:both; between content and bar divs

Comment: actually I have div tag before this save cancel button...is it possible to set the height of the div, so that it will fill the space and display the save cancel buttons when I run the application?

Comment: thanks alot Irish, your code is working fine, I have a doubt here, If use the min-length of div tag as <div id="content" style="min-height:210px;"></div>....this alone satisfied my requirement...here I set the height as 210px, if I run the same application in different systems will the alignment vary according to their monitor size

Comment: It's a trade off; you could use % values to fix it for a wide range of monitor sizes :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, what I got you want to move buttons at bottom of page:

```
<div class="bottomBar">
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="bar">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</div>
```

and css

```
.bottomBar
{
float :bottom;
}

.bar
{
background-position: center;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCCC;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 30px;
border-top-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: @Shanish I think above code will solve your problem you can adjust further position by setting {margin-bottom : 100px}

Comment: actually I have div tag before this save cancel button...is it possible to set the height of the div, so that it will fill the space and display the save cancel buttons when I run the application?

Comment: you can set div height to 98% and bar height to 2%

Answer (score 1):

Add those two lines to your .bar:

```
.bar
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
/* the rest of your code */
}
```

Comment: no if I put the position:absolute, it will disturb the alignments in other forms, coz am using this same bar style in all my forms......in other forms I have the controls that fills the page and automatically the save cancel buttons are coming at the bottom, but here I have only 4 controls...so the save and cancel button is at center, thats what am trying to display at the buttom

Comment: you could use two different css classes, for example .bar wich is your original code, and a .footer_bar for the bar at the bottom of your page

Answer (score 1):

Hi now you can define table align right and two class create in css as like this 
**Css**

```
.bar
{
background-position: center;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCCC;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 30px;
border-top-style: solid;
}

.save{width:100px;
height:20px;
background:green;
display: inline-block;}

.cancel{width:100px;
height:20px;
background:red;
display: inline-block;}
```

**HTML**

```
<table align="right">
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="bar">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" class="save"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"  class="cancel"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/a9uym/